# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException : Invalid object name , after updating dot net framework

Tags: c#, ef-code-first

I updated my solution from framework 4 to 4.5.2
However some of the annotations are not working.

I have class

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace SBD.PreflightData.DataObjects
{
    [Table("xVivConfig")]
    public partial class VivConfig
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
        public string Comment { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and in the DbContext I have

```
public DbSet<VivConfig> VivConfigs { get; set; }
```

When I run my test I get an error

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException : Invalid object name 'dbo.VivConfig'.
```

I can work around the issue by adding

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<VivConfig>().ToTable("xVivConfig");
```

in the OnModelCreating

but I want to understand why the attribute is ignored.

I have re-installed Entity Framework after upgrading
I do have a similar project working correctly for the same database.

Rolling back to the 4.0 causes solves the problem but I need to be on the later Framework

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved by uninstalling and reinstalling Entity Frameworks in all projects, including the test project.

Comment: I think the issue was caused by the wrong  version of EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll  and EntityFramework.SqlServer.xml